# Facebook Login With Facebook4j API?

Tags: java, facebook

I am using Facebook4j for interaction with facebook through my Java web application . i want to know What Data I have to save Into database So Next time When user come to my application no need to further

```
        String code = request.getParameter(OAUTH_CODE);
        if (code != null && code.length() > 0) {

            LOGGER.debug("We have a oauth code: {}.", code);
            LOGGER.debug("Attempting to verify the code...");

            Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);

            LOGGER.debug("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");

            Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);

            Token accessToken1 = new Token(token, apiSecret);
```

And now save these `accessToken1` into database but everytime when i login from diffrent account i am getting same `AccessToken` ..What i am doing wrong? or what information i have to save into database

Answer (score 0):

Where is your OAUTH_CODE coming from?  If that is the same each time then your token will be the same too.  How about the variable "token"?  Is that your FB APP ID?  So AccessToken1 is the APP token and accessToken is the user token?

Comment: I would question whether you are really getting a different FB user each time.  The code has the be different each time and therefore the verifier and therefore the token, but you can have many tokens for the same FB account.  I would look closely at how you are verifying you are logging into different FB user accounts on the FB side.

Comment: We save the ID in our app and it appears to last longer than 2 hours.  I think we have one that has lasted 6 months so far.  Did you verify you are logging in as different users?  Maybe use different computers and browsers to test?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind OAUTH is, that a user authorizes an app to do things in his/her name for a short amount of time. After is amount of time has passed the user has to authorize that app again. So there is nothing you can save that will help, your app will always need user interaction ;)

Comment: But in Case of Twitter we can save AccessToken See **After you acquired the AccessToken for the user, the RequestToken is not required anymore. You can persist the AccessToken to any kind of persistent store such as RDBMS, or File system by serializing the object, or by geting the token and the secret from AccessToken#getToken() and AccessToken#getTokenSecret(). **  [http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html]

Comment: It seems that twitter access tokens do not expire but the facebook ones do after 2 hours: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: hmm Strange so no way to do operation from Token even user authorized my web application

Comment: So how Stackoverflow work on Facebook login every time user have to login into Stackoverflow? I think No ts due to they have token so they used same token again please tell if i am wrong?